# css link is not working. What can i do?

Tags: html, css

My css style link isnt working
I am a beginner and am trying to make a website.
I wrote the link in the header tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
```

Comment: the main.css is placed in a folder named "styles" which is in the same emplacement with you html file?

Comment: Please send the whole HTML file, please.

Comment: I just deleted styles and it was gone. Guy in YouTube Video didnt say that one had to create a styles Felder.

Comment: you can write your css code inside <style> code here </style> also.

Comment: Ok thanks for the Tipp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. First locate the folder where you saved your HTML file.
2. Create a folder named styles
3. In that styles folder, create your css file named main.css
4. Open that "main.css" file with notepad or notepad++(what you feel comfortable with), write your css code and save it.

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code provided, it says your .css file in "styles" folder where your .html file located.

Check and make sure it is as it is. if not try to correct it. Case sensitive are also applied to this path.

Thank you.